# Best way to disable @KafkaListeners

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My application contains several `@KafkaListeners`.
When I run the app locally or run some `@SpringBootTests` (without kafka), I got my log polluted with

> [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-app-1, groupId=app] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

For such cases, I would like to disable listeners, as they are useless anyways.
I know I can do it with

```
@KafkaListener(... autoStartup = "${consumer.auto.start:false}")
```

but adding this property to all of the consumers feels cumbersome.

Unfortunately, there is no general property like `spring.kafka.consumer.group-id` that would affect all the consumers.

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in Spring for Apache Kafka activity in some of your Spring Boot tests, just consider to exclude its auto-configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

This way the `@EnableKafka` won't be applied to your application context and no `KafkaListenerContainer`s are going to be registered to start on context refresh.

**UPDATE**

Another way, for the reason you explained, a respective configuration property, which you can add to `application.properties`, which could be a test scope-specific, or profile-based. See more info in Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration

The property name is `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` - you have to specify fully-qualified class name. Therefore for your use-case it is:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```

See also how to have test-specific `application.properties` or divided by the profile: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles

Comment: That's also a good approach, thank you. But it will require to add this annotation to every test (or have a common config/parent, but you still add that line). I don't think it solves the problem with just running the app locally though.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: The `autoStartup` on the `@RabbitListener` overrides the default setting in the container factory which is set using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.auto-startup and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.auto-startup depending on your listener type. You can set them all to false with one property setting.

Comment: Gary, the question is about Spring for Apache Kafka. Doesn't look like we have similar option to the mentioned for Spring AMQP...